# SQL windows function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am new in SQL and I try to query a database using PostgreSQL (9.6).

When I write the following code I have and error syntax with the windows function:

```
/* Ranking total of rental movie by film category (I use the sakila database) */

SELECT category_name, rental_count
FROM
    (SELECT c.name category_name, Count(r.rental_id) rental_count
    FROM category c
    JOIN film_category USING (category_id)
    JOIN inventory USING (film_id)
    JOIN rental r USING (inventory_id)
    JOIN film f USING (film_id)
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER by 2, 1
     ) sub
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category_name ORDER BY rental_count DESC) AS total_rank
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
SELECT c.name as category_name, COUNT(*) as rental_count,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
FROM category c JOIN
     film_category USING (category_id) JOIN
     inventory USING (film_id) JOIN
     rental r USING (inventory_id) JOIN
     film f USING (film_id)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER by 2, 1;
```

You also don't need the join to `film`, because you are using nothing from that table.

Your query fails because the column list goes in the `SELECT` clause.  The `FROM` list follows the `SELECT`.

Comment: I have the same output when using this: SELECT category_name, rental_count, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category_name ORDER BY rental_count DESC) AS total_rank
FROM
 (SELECT c.name category_name, Count(r.rental_id) rental_count
 FROM category c
 JOIN film_category USING (category_id)
 JOIN inventory USING (film_id)
 JOIN rental r USING (inventory_id)
 JOIN film f USING (film_id)
 GROUP BY 1
  ) sub 
 ORDER by 2, 1;

Comment: Thank you so much dear Gordon Linoff, you are right I really don;t need a subquery, and I see clear now with your answer. You are the best my friend. Thank you again! By the way I just use the GROUP BY 1 instead of GROUP BY 1, 2.